# How to connect to Shared MailBox with oAuth on Powershell

Tags: powershell, imap, mailkit

I wrote code for connecting Mail with OAuth.
However, I need to connect with Shered MailBox.
Please teach me how to connect to Shered MailBox

```
# Options
$options = [Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationOptions]::new()
$options.ClientId = $ClientID
$options.TenantId = $TenantID
$options.RedirectUri = $RedirectUri
# Scope
$scopes = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$scopes.Add("https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All")

$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Pass -AsPlainText -Force
$PublicClientApplication = [Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder]::CreateWithApplicationOptions($Options).Build()

# AuthToken
$AuthToken = $PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword($Scopes, $UserName, $securePass).ExecuteAsync() | Wait-Task   
$oAuth2 = [MailKit.Security.SaslMechanismOAuth2]::new($authToken.Account.Username, $authToken.AccessToken)

# IMAP
$client = [MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient]::new()  
$client.ConnectAsync($Server, $Port, $Options) | Wait-Task | Out-Null
# ログイン
$client.AuthenticateAsync($oAuth2) | Wait-Task | Out-Null
```